# How to start Apple Watch app when user makes some action in iOS app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I was told multiple times that other apps do this but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do that.

The behavior I would like to achieve is:

1. User starts iOS app and navigates to particular screen.
2. User presses start action/workout button and starts action/workout on iOS app.
3. At the same time user's Watch wakes up and shows corresponding screen in Watch app which acts as info screen for the current action/workout in iOS app.
4. User can press pause button on Watch and pause the action/workout in iOS app (this part is working already via WCSession).

So the question is basically how can I launch Watch app when either iOS app starts or when user does something in iOS app?

P.S. It is not a question of launching iOS app from Watch app, AFAIK for that I can use handoff.